# VBA: DataBodyRange does not define the whole pivot table

Tags: excel, range, pivot-table, vba

I have a question concerning the Property DataBodyRange

I have a simple pivot table (Range from column D to F) with 3 columns:

```
Dim PvtSht As Worksheet
Dim pvtFld As PivotField
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim i As Long
Dim data_fields As Variant

data_fields = Array("ACCNTNUM", "ACCNTNAME", "PRICE")
PvtSht.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow

For i = 0 To UBound(data_fields)
  Set pvtFld = pvt.PivotFields(data_fields(i))
  pvtFld.Orientation = xlRowField
  PvtSht.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(data_fields(i)).Subtotals(1) = False
  PvtSht.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ColumnGrand = False
Next
```

Ultimately, I would like to change the format of the table. Therefore, I need the DataBodyRange so that VBA knows where the changes need to be applied to. However when I check this DataBodyRange:

```
Debug.Print pvt.DataBodyRange.Addres
```

It only gives me the range of the last column (F). As soon as I remove a column, it still gives me the range of the last column (E).

The pivot tables starts here

```
Set pvt = PvtSht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pvtCache, TableDestination:=PvtSht.Range("D3"), TableName:="PivotTable1")
```

So my question is, how can I change DataBodyRange so that the whole table (D:F) is defined and not just one column (F).

Please let me know if any of this is not clear enough.

Comment: to get all the columns in `DataBodyRange` you will need to loop through `DataBodyRange.Columns` one by one, and then use the `Union` to get what you want, let me know if you need help with that

Comment: The DataBodyRange is only the section which is represented by Values (the aggregations). Not rowfield pivotitems.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more on what you are actually trying to achieve with this code snippet. The code snippet you have posted doesn't really make sense and so it's hard to offer help without a plain English description of what it is you want to do.